# What is the maximum time for UK Tier 2 dependent visa review?

Tags: united-kingdom, immigration, dependent-visa, application-status

My wife and child applied for UK dependent visa (tier 2) but got refused. They applied for a review, the review team contacted and said they will reconsider their application and asked to submit the passports and other documents. My wife submitted those documents, but it is more than 1.5 months we couldn't get any answer from the review team. My wife contacted them again and asked whether they received the documents or not. They replied the following:

"Every application is subject to mandatory checks which have to be made before a decision can be taken. A decision on your applications shall be made as soon as we receive the results of our enquiries. I am afraid it is not possible to tell you exactly when we will receive these results."

Does anybody know how long it is going to take to get the results?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer you got is the best guess.  The review process is not subject to UKVI's customer standards of processing time.  In reality, they cannot give you an estimate because it may compromise their security and risk measurement.

You wrote that the process has taken 1.5 months so far, after it has taken the full constitutionally mandated 90 days you can initiate a formal enquiry.  Bugging them about it before 90 days will invariably slow the process because somebody has to go and find your stuff.

In all events, it's better if your sponsor initiate the enquiry.